# How to reduce swipeAction distance for cells in a tableview in swift? (Like WhatsApp context reply functionality)

Tags: ios, swift

this is the action that I am using. The swiping action executes the first action on a very long swipe to right. How can this execution of action be done with just half swipe towards right

```
let modifyAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title:  "", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
        print("yess....")
        success(true)
    })
    modifyAction.image = UIImage(named: "cross")
    modifyAction.backgroundColor = AppColors.blackColorWith0PercentOpacity

    let action = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [modifyAction])
    action.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = true
    return action
```

Comment: there is no public api available related to this

Comment: Hey, Have you found a solution for this??

Answer (score 0):

Swiping nothing but touching and moving the screen.

With overriding `touchesBegan`,`touchesMoved`,`touchesEnded` on your viewController or UITableView you can write your own swipe and decide how to measure full, half swipes.